# Отловить событие во внутреннем iframe с другого домена

Tags: javascript, iframe

Имеется сайт,  в нем, в "попапе" , загружается iframe с другого домена, необходимо отловить событие происходящее в iframe и обработать его уже в самом сайте
Прошу подобрать какое нибудь решение ( postmessage или что то другое - неважно )

Comment: Same-origin policy не позволит.

Answer (score 1):

Отловить самому не получиться, во-первых доступа у вас туда нет по причинам безопасности, cross-domain очень сильно ограничен. Едиственная существующая возможность это общаться через нативный `postMessage`

Для этого вам понадобится с начала в сам ифрейм добавить отсылку нужных данных

```
   parent.postMessage({array:[1,2]},"*");  //  `*` или ваш домен
```

А в главном фрейме добавит обработчик этих данных.

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Ждём сообщений от внутреннего фрейма...
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
     console.log(e.data); //Object {array: Array[2]}
},false);
```

в этом случае ещё кое как можно общаться cross-domain.

взято у [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe)